# Failed to get oauth_token for vimeo advanced api

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, vimeo, vimeo-api

After wondering from everywhere, i need to ask about my question. 
I want to access vimeo advanced api without user login. Application user directly can see videos or upload.

Following code i'm using to get this functionality but i suffer from different kind of errors :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.oauth.checkAccessToken"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

__weak NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth realm=%@, oauth_consumer_key=%@, oauth_version=%@, oauth_signature_method=%@, oauth_timestamp=%@, oauth_nonce=%@, oauth_token=%@, oauth_signature=%@ ", @"", @"409ca6030dfad27f133f22d48a9a40b7153c920d", @"1.0", @"HMAC-SHA1", @"1402387904", @"b8c8435e4aa9c9ae3f1c621e1c58c99f", @"f91469717363c5710271f6f3c2540f49", @"wOJIO9A2W5mFwDgiDvZbTSMK%2FPY%3D"];

[request setValue:req forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[urlConnection start];
```

I got response like :

```
err =     {
    code = 401;
    expl = "The oauth_signature passed was not valid.";
    msg = "Invalid signature";
};
```

I already tried for oauth_signature and also different ways to achieve this task but then i got error for "Invalid Consumer Key".

I need to solve this problem as soon as possible.
Any help will be surely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is actually oauth1.0, not 2.0 but it seems SO doesn't have a 1.0 tag?

Comment: @Dashron : Thanks for replying but if i exclude SO tag then it gives me error for "Missing Parameters". Can you please provides me more clarification, if possible.

Comment: by SO I meant stack overflow, I was just trying to help tag things. My first recommendation is always to use an existing OAuth 1 lib, but I'm not familiar with objective c.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get access token before you implement this, I have found a nice tutorial for you for implementation of getting vimeo access token
http://codegerms.com/login-with-vimeo-in-ios-app-using-oauth-tutorial/